# Is it good idea to share same xml file for two activities?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am bit confused whether to use same xml or different xml for two activities.One activities is to add an event and second activity is to edit an event.

I don't want to duplicate the xml file.How should I approach this situation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No issues,you can use the same xml(if it is upto your requirements )

Comment: Even you can use same Activity for this purpose. While editing you can pass all data into extra, and for add do not pass data. At oncreate of that activity you can check extra and show data if you found for edit, otherwise this will be the case for add.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `setContentView` from the activity class your approach should be perfectly ok. I've done something similar before

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the same activity and use the proper launch mode as per your business logic.
Use The intent passed in onCreate() of course to decide why the activity is launched